# Correct HTML Component div must be used with appropriate constraints false

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Specification:**

Create a web page which calculates the discount for the product for the specific season. The seasons with their discount rates are summer (10%), new year (5%) and clearance (15%). The discount is calculated on the price of the product. The web page should look like

The web page is designed using HTML, formatting and styling is done using CSS. The client side validation is performed using JavaScript.

Web page Requirements

The name of the web page is "index.html". The web page background color should be #99FFFF. The label “Discount Price” should be a heading tag(h1) and should be italic bolded, centered, and in maroon color.

Product name, price and season should be within a table. Product name and price are `text` box with the tag name “name” and “price” respectively, `season` is a drop down box with tag name “season”. The drop down box will have the following value and display value

```
    ·         summer           -           SUMMER SALE

    ·         newyear          -           NEW YEAR SALE

    ·         clearance        -           CLEARANCE SALE
```

Product Name should not be empty and should contain only alphabets and space. The Price text box cannot be empty and should be `number` with `value` greater than zero.

The table should be margin-left aligned with 35% and an outer border-style of solid 5px and 30% width. The space between `element` and the border must be 10px.

A submit button with a value “GET DISCOUNT PRICE” should be present. On clicking the button the web page calculates the discounted price for the product.

The outcome must be displayed in 2 div tags, where the first will have the id named “discount” and is to display the discount % of the product and the second will have the id named “result” and is to display the discounted price of the product. Both the div tag should be `center` aligned with `bolder` text. The `font` of the discounted price must be italic #FF0000 and 40px size and for discount % it is 25px. Have separate styles for div, discount and result

**CSS:**

```
{
    background-color: #99FFFF;
}
h1{
    color:maroon;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style:italic;
}
table,td{
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-left: 35%;
    width: 30%;
}
div{
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#result{
    font-style:italic;
    color:#FF0000 ;
    font-size:40px;
}
#discount{
    font-size:25px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function discount()
{
    var s = document.getElementById("season").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var r;

    if (s=='summer')
    {
        document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML = "The discount is 10%";
        r=(p-(p*0.1));
    }
    else if(s=='newyear')
    {
        document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML = "The discount is 5%";
        r=(p-(p*0.05));
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML = "The discount is 15%";
        r=(p-(p*0.15));
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The discount price: Rs " + r;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>index.html</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>DISCOUNT PRICE</h1>
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Price</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price"  id="price" min="1"  ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Season</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="season" name="season">
                            <option value="summer">SUMMER SALE</option>
                            <option value="newyear">NEW YEAR SALE</option>
                            <option value="clearance">CLEARANCE SALE</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <center><input type="button" value="GET DISCOUNT PRICE" onclick="discount()"></center>
        </form>
        <div id="discount"></div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Error:**

> testWeb(jspackage.JSAssignmentDiscount):
>   Correct HTML Component div must be used with appropriate constraints
>   false

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: I am not asking to solve this problem for me or to do homework for me. I have already solved it everything according to the specification but getting some error while evaluating so I am just clearing my doubt where I have committed the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use following line as per above mentioned constraints on 'price'-

```
<input type="text" name="price" id="price" pattern="[\d]+" min="1" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for price component:

```
<input type="text" name="price" required pattern="[1-9]{1}[1-9]*">
```

Answer (score 0):

A submit button with a value “GET DISCOUNT PRICE” should be present. 
just read this line .He has used type="button" but it should be type="submit"
actually i am doing the same question right now.